# CSS not working in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome

It's on a simple asp.net web project. There's a Styles folder in the project and in that folder are four css files all pretty simple. Main.css has this:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 85%;
width: 700px;
height: 900px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px;
background-color: green;
}
```

The green (it was originally white) shows up in IE but not in Chrome. I reference the css files in the ASPX file:

```
<link href="Styles/CheckOut.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="Styles/Main.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The green was only one test. I made other changes to the css files and none showed up in Chrome. Aside from the css issue, the app performs fine in Chrome as well as IE.

The Page Inspector reflects the css files; but Chrome does not. There are a couple of similar seeming questions here but none address my issue, AFAIK.

Comment: The rule has always been, "If it works in IE but not the other browsers, your markup is wrong."  There isn't anything there that shows an obvious problem so you need to create a jsfiddle or a link that shows the problem. Also, <link> tags do not have a closing slash. Remove that.

Comment: fixed the closing slash issue. Cannot use a link as this is only local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page in Chrome, do you have dev tools open?  And if you do, do you have "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" checked?  I've found that Chrome is pretty aggressive about caching stuff, so if you're not seeing your changes this might be something to look into.  (You can verify if that checkbox is marked by hitting F12 on Windows or option-command-I on Mac, and clicking on the widget wheel.  It's the first checkbox under "General".)

Comment: That was it. I emptied the cache and now everything is working great. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!